# How to mapConcat() and then fold() in a nested Flow before the upstream completes

Tags: scala, akka-stream

Basically I'm trying to achieve the following scenario, that I consider a very simple use case. But as I'm new to akka-streams, I don't get it right.

At a certain stage of my stream graph, I split up N elements using the `mapConcat` function, then processing each of them in a nested flow in parallel and afterwards folding them again. **The amount N of sub elements emitted by `mapConcat` is not know in advance** and can differ from zero to hundreds of elements. But the fold function as stated in the [docs](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akkhttps://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/operators/Sink/fold.htmla/current/stream/operators/Sink/fold.html)  only completes if the upstream completes, but I need a fan-in stage that does it, once all elements, that have been splitted by the `mapConcat` stage, have been processed.

[image: nested Flow with mapConcat and fold]

A minimal example would be something like that:

```
Source(1 to 10)
  .via(
     Flow[Int].map(el => el * el))
  .via(
     Flow[Int]
       .mapConcat(el => Set(el + 1, el + 2, el + 3))
       .map(el => el * el)
       .fold(0)((all, cur) => all + cur)
     )
  .runForeach(println)
```

For an interactive example see: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/hPdKEF4QS0yZazWMfFvuEQ

The fold operation folds all values, so it prints one value. How to construct the flow in order to get 10 results?

Answer (score 1):

[mapConcat](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/stream/operators/Source-or-Flow/mapConcat.html) applies a function to every element in an input stream and concatenate in the output stream.  While having a slightly simpler signature, it operates like `flatMapConcat` and can probably be best illustrated with the following diagram from this [Akka Stream doc](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/stream-substream.html#flatmapconcat).

[image]

With the above picture in mind, to review the flow content per Source element, you can use `grouped` to group the mapConcat-ed data, as shown below:

```
import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import akka.stream.ActorMaterializer
import akka.stream.scaladsl._

implicit val system = ActorSystem("system")
implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()

Source(1 to 10).
  via(
    Flow[Int].map(el => el * el)).
  via(
    Flow[Int].
      mapConcat(el => Set(el + 1, el + 2, el + 3)).
      map(el => el * el).
      grouped(3).
      map{ g =>
        val sum = g.reduce(_ + _)
        println(s"$g: sum = $sum")
        sum
      }.
      fold(0)(_ + _)
    ).
  runForeach(println)

// res1: scala.concurrent.Future[akka.Done] = Future(<not completed>)
// Vector(4, 9, 16): sum = 29
// Vector(25, 36, 49): sum = 110
// Vector(100, 121, 144): sum = 365
// Vector(289, 324, 361): sum = 974
// Vector(676, 729, 784): sum = 2189
// Vector(1369, 1444, 1521): sum = 4334
// Vector(2500, 2601, 2704): sum = 7805
// Vector(4225, 4356, 4489): sum = 13070
// Vector(6724, 6889, 7056): sum = 20669
// Vector(10201, 10404, 10609): sum = 31214
// 80759
```

[UPDATE]

If the Iterable generated by `mapConcat` varies in size per Source element, `grouped` will no longer be helpful.  In some cases, you might be able to move any post-mapConcat transformations into the body of the function taken by `mapConcat`, like in the following example:

```
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom

Source(1 to 10).
  via(
    Flow[Int].map(el => el * el)).
  via(
    Flow[Int].
      mapConcat{ el =>
        val list = for (i <- 1 to ThreadLocalRandom.current.nextInt(1, 4))
          yield el + i
        val list2 = list.map(e => e * e)
        val sum = list2.reduce(_ + _)
        println(s"$list2: sum = $sum")
        list2
      }.
      fold(0)(_ + _)
    ).
  runForeach(println)

// res2: scala.concurrent.Future[akka.Done] = Future(<not completed>)
// Vector(4): sum = 4
// Vector(25, 36, 49): sum = 110
// Vector(100, 121, 144): sum = 365
// Vector(289): sum = 289
// Vector(676, 729): sum = 1405
// Vector(1369): sum = 1369
// Vector(2500, 2601, 2704): sum = 7805
// Vector(4225, 4356): sum = 8581
// Vector(6724, 6889, 7056): sum = 20669
// Vector(10201, 10404): sum = 20605
// 61202
```

Comment: A very important detail, I forgot to mention in my question is, that I do not know the amount of elements, emitted by the mapConcat operation in advance. For each source element it can be everything from zero to hundreds of elements. The example I posted is not very good and is really just a dumb simplification of a much more complex system.

Comment: @SeDav, please see expanded answer re: your additional requirement.

Comment: Thank you for your effort, but in reality I operate on graph data that wil be transformed into json structures and at some point (but only in certain flow graphs) they get splitted and separately processed results have to merged again. Maybe I should do it with `groupBy` and remember some context along the streaming pipeline or go with real sub streams.

Comment: Perhaps you might also want to check out `MergeHub/BroadcastHub` in the Akka doc re: [dynamic fan-in/fan-out](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/stream-dynamic.html?language=scala#dynamic-fan-in-and-fan-out-with-mergehub-broadcasthub-and-partitionhub).

Answer (score 1):

you can get your 10 elements via grouping by N (N : number of results emitted by mapConcat):

```
Source(1 to 10)
.via(
  Flow[Int].map(el => el * el))
.via(
  Flow[Int]
    .mapConcat(el => Set(el + 1, el + 2, el + 3))
    .map(el => el * el)
    .grouped(3)
    .map(s => s.sum))
.runForeach(println)
```

But mapConcat does not create a substream, it just takes a single element and emits N. All on the same stream.

If on the other hand you really wanted to create substreams I'd suggest having a look at [akka-doc#substream](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/stream-substream.html)